# Do DynamoDB and Cloudant store data at edge locations?

Tags: couchdb, amazon-dynamodb, pouchdb, cloudant

Trying to decide between DynamoDB and CouchDB for my website. It's a static site (built with a static site generator) and I'm planning on using a JavaScript module to build a comment system.

I'm toying with using PouchDB and CouchDB so that synchronizing is easy. I'm also considering DynamoDB.

I have a performance question. From these databases, do any of them push data out to edge locations so that latency is reduced? Or is my Database essentially sitting on one virtual server somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, neither of these solutions utilise edge locations ootb.

Since you're mentioning PouchDB, I assume you want to use a client-side database in your app?

If that's the case you should keep in mind that, in order to sync, a client-side DB needs to have access to your cloud db. So it's not really suitable for a comment system since all client could just drop comments of others, edit them, etc.